# I cant seem to make a multi arg cucumber test - Ruby on Rails

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am trying to do something that should be fairly simple.  I want to make a Cucumber test that has 2 arguments.  One is a name and another is a number.  Here is what I have that is not working:

```
When /^I add a credit to "([^\"]*)" for (\d+)$/ do |kid, amount|
  ...
end
```

I am getting the amount piece, but it will not locate the name.  I have looked around and sometimes I see the expression in quotes and other times they are not.  An explanation would be great.  Obviously I suck at regex, but I have been spinning in circles for an hour on this.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: instead of (\d+), if you use ([0-9]+) .. is it working?

Comment: Changed question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
When /^I add a credit to "([^"]*)" for (\d+)$/ do |kid, amount|
end
```

If it is not helped then removed this step from file and run scenarios without step defintion and cucumber will generate suitable blank step definition.

For example

```
Given(/^have attempted to click the 'verify_purchase_button' button$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Comment: I used (.+) which of course will match anything, but it was sufficient for these particular tests.  When I tried to let Rails generate the expression, I could never get it to generate an expression with more than one argument.